# Removing Nodes matching a specific attribute value

Tags: xml, powershell, powershell-2.0

I have XML data similar to:

```xml
<objects>
  <object>
    <property name="a" />
    <property name="b" />
    <property name="hasErrors" />
    <property name="data" />
        <property/>
        <property/>
    </property>
  </object>
</objects>
```

In PowerShell, how would I remove nodes that have specific values for attribute `name`? More specifically, I want to remove nodes and their children (if any) with names "hasErrors" and "data".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This snippet should help you,I am using Xpath to match conditions:

```
[xml]$data = @"
<objects>
  <object>
    <property name="a" />
    <property name="b" />
    <property name="hasErrors" />
    <property name="data" />
        <property/>
        <property/>
  </object>
</objects>
"@

 $data.SelectNodes("//property[@name = 'data' or @name = 'hasErrors']") | % {$_.ParentNode.removechild($_) } | Out-Null
 #to view properties,the empty nodes aren't visible as no value is inside.You can confirm them with count or after saving
$data.objects.object.property
$data.Save("C:\yourpath\mydata.xml")
```